What determines whether a vowel is ATR?
How would one determine if some vowel has an advanced tongue root (ATR) or retracted tongue root (RTR)?
For example: is /y/ ATR or RTR?

When you pronounce [y] and try to retract your tongue, and it's possible and it starts sounding different, then you have evidence that [y] was +advancedTR. Or am I missing something?

@Alazon Is there a way to determine if it’s +ATR based on the backness or height of the vowel? /e/ is ATR and /ε/ is RTR. Would that imply that /ø/ is ATR and /œ/ is RTR?
